# Leaving cities with less than X number of observation in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, definition-query

I would like to generate some quintile maps based on the averaged sentiment score in each city in the US. However, not all the city has the same number of data point. How can I tell ArcGIS to show averaged sentiment score in each city that has at least, say 100, data points and leave the ones with less than 100 data points blank?

To be more specific, I have some csv data with latitude and longitude,

1. I first import XY as csv into ArcGIS,
2. then I export this csv into .shp file,
3. each XY point contains a sentiment score, and ultimately I would like to get an averaged sentiment score of each city,
4. I then spatially join the new .shp file containing my data with a base file of US city, and the aggregation method is to average the sentiment points into one averaged score per city,
5. then I would like to generate quintile map based on the averaged sentiment score.

I just want the final quintile map leave those cities with less than 100 data points originally. I am not sure how and where I can specify when I generate the final quintile map to look into the original data in .shp and screen out the cities that don't have at least 100 data points.

---

Although I am getting more knowledgeable about how to select data via Query, it doesn't address my issues:

1. I don't see any reference from their document of how to query based on number of data points (they have given an example of using "population" variable > 1000, but it's not the same); and
2. even if I can successfully select cities satisfied the threshold data points, I still need to join all areas with the base map and the final map will still see cities with less than 100 data points as having 0 averaged sentiment.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to apply a definition query to that layer for something like "NumDataPoints >= 100" but there may be more to your question so please use the [edit] button to provide more precise details if you think I have over simplified what you are asking.

Comment: Editing added, where and how do I perform your suggestion?

Comment: Definition queries are documented at http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002z000000

Comment: Thanks although I am getting more knowledgeable about how to select data via Query, it doesn't address my issues: 1) I don't see any reference from their document of how to query based on number of data points (they have given an example of using "population" variable > 1000, but it's not the same); and 2) even if I can successfully select cities satisfied the threshold data points, I still need to join all areas with the base map and the final map will still see cities with less than 100 data points as having 0 averaged sentiment.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to revise it with additional details such as these rather than creating a comment trail that potential answerers may or may not read.  Using the definition query relies on there being a field for each city that holds a count of the number of data points within it.  If you don't have that then I would suggest that there is a question you need to resolve before you can get to this one.

Comment: If you do the spatial join correctly, the output table should have a join count column. *That* is the field you would do the definition query on, because that's your datapoint count. I'm not sure you could do a definition query that's based on the count of records with a particular value in a specific field. I don't really understand your 2nd issue - with the definition query, any city with less than 100 joins won't show up at all. You may need/want to export the results of the def query (or just those records without even bothering with a def query) to a new file for your final map join.

Comment: Thanks Chris you are correct, I just checked the joined data and found out there is a _count, if you like, please write that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: It's really @PolyGeo's answer, I just provided a little clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to apply a definition query to that layer for something like:

```
"NumDataPoints >= 100"
```

Definition queries are described in the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002z000000):

> When you specify a dataset that you want to draw as a map layer, you
>   often only want to draw some of the features in the dataset. In these
>   situations, you can define a query expression to select a subset of
>   features for the layer display. This is referred to as a definition
>   query.